# USB not working with a 3D printer

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint

I got an Ultimaker Original+ 3D printer, which works fine when connected to my Windows 7 PC. But when I connect it to my Mint Linux PC, it isn't detected at all: Cura (the 3D printing software) is not detecting the 3D printer at all. I tried it with all 3 USB ports (USB 2 ports) available on my Linux computer (a 2008 Asus laptop, with a Centrino). But those ports are working fine when connected to a mouse or a hard drive, for example. What can be done?

Comment: You will have to provide a driver compatible with the printer and Linux.

Comment: Shouldn't it at least detect an unknown USB device?